# How can I move the code from Access to MSSQL

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have already project file working on my computer with localhost and access database.

Access Database Code:

```html
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/Database2.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [Price] FROM [GENERAL] WHERE ([ProductID] = ?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

```html
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings: blabla %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [Price] FROM [GENERAL] WHERE ([ProductID] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I connect my project to MSSQL database. Everything works if I use the code `SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [Price] FROM [GENERAL]`. I need to do more specific. What did I miss? I expect results on Gridview related to `[ProductID]`. But, it shows:

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '?'."

Answer (score 1):

You should not use ? inline parameters with SqlServer. That's fine for Access data sources, but not fine for SQL. You should use named parameters instead. Try this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings: blabla %>" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [Price] FROM [GENERAL] WHERE ([ProductID] = @ProductID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Also, how are you setting the SelectParam? Via a control or via the code? It looks like it is unset right now.